# Parallel Operations

Tags: c, valgrind, matrix-multiplication

So I am making a program that can read in multiple matrices from a binary input file and write the binary results into an output file. What I also need to do is do matrix multiplication between the two current matrices and use a sort algorithm after multiplying. After I get this done need to use Mutex to help make this program more of a parallel operation.
This is what I am using and came up with and granted its not complete:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct matrix {
    int row;
    int column;
};

// mult_matrices() does not operate on two matrices
// show_matrices() does not write matrix headers or final 0-0 marker
// elapsed time is not calculated right

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int x = *(int *)a;
  int y = *(int *)b;

  if (x<y) 
    return -1; 
  if (x>y) 
    return 1; 
  return 0;
}

struct matrix matrices;

int num_argc;
int size = (100 * 8);
//size_t nbytes = 2 * sizeof(int);
int fd_read;
int fd_write;
int **matrices_size;
int **matrices_values;
int **Matrices_results;

int **current;
int holder;

int count_nsize;
int count_nvalue;

char * input_file;
char * output_file;

void read_matrices() 
{
    //this will read in what is inside the binary file and create the desired matrices
    //this will make the size of the matrix
    fd_read = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);
    if(fd_read < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to read and open the file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    //Dynamically allocate memory for the pointer to pointer
    matrices_size = malloc(size);
    matrices_values = malloc(size);
    while (read(fd_read, &matrices, 2 * sizeof(int)) == 2 * sizeof(int))
    {
        if (matrices.row != 0 && matrices.column != 0)
        {
            matrices_size[count_nsize] = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
            /*
            turn the 1d array that has been dynamically allocated with nbytes to a 2d array with the same name 
            the reasoning for you to do this is so that you won't have an overflow in the 2d array
            */
            matrices_size[count_nsize][0] = matrices.row;
            matrices_size[count_nsize][1] = matrices.column;
            count_nsize++;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        matrices_values[count_nvalue] = malloc(matrices.row * matrices.column * 4);
        if(read(fd_read, matrices_values[count_nvalue], (matrices.row * matrices.column * 4)) != (matrices.row * matrices.column * 4)) break;
        count_nvalue++;
    }
    //free(fd_read);
    close(fd_read);
}

void mult_matrices() {

   // Multiplying first and second matrices and storing it in result
   //then we will also sort each row in ascending order
   //size = 100 * 8
   Matrices_results = malloc(size);
   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < matrices_size[0][0]; i++)
   {
       Matrices_results = malloc(matrices_size[1][1]);
       for (int j = 0; j < matrices_size[1][1]; j++)
       {
           Matrices_results[i][j] += matrices_values[i][k] * matrices_values[k][j];
           k++;
       }
       
   }
    //placing the results in the global variable so it can be used in the show function.


}

void show_matrices() {
    // this will show the new matrices after multiplying 
    // this is where we will also sort each row in ascending order
    fd_write = open(output_file, O_CREAT|O_WRONLY,0666);
    if (fd_write < 0)
    {
        printf("Failed to create and open the file\n");
        close(fd_write);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (write(fd_write, *Matrices_results, 2 * sizeof(int)) == 2 * sizeof(int))
    {
        if(write(fd_write, *Matrices_results,(matrices.row * matrices.column * 4)) != (matrices.row * matrices.column * 4)) break;
    }
    //holder = write(fd_write, Matrices_results, (matrices.row * matrices.column * 4));
    close(fd_write);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    input_file = argv[1];
    output_file = argv[2];
    num_argc = argc;
    if(num_argc != 3)
    {
        printf("you are missing an input or output file name\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    uint64_t diff,writ,comp,rd;
    struct timespec start, end;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

    //read in the matrices
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    read_matrices();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    rd = 1000000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("Reading:       %9luns\n", rd);


    //compute the matrices
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    mult_matrices();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
     comp= 1000000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("Compute:       %9luns\n", comp);

    //writes out the new matrices
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    show_matrices();
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    writ = 1000000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("Writing:       %9luns\n", writ);

    //computes the total elapsed time
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
    diff = 1000000000 * (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) + end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec;
    printf("Elapsed:       %9luns\n", diff);

    return 0;
}
```

gcc -Wall -Werror -O2 matrix.c -o mm

valgrind --leak-check=yes -q --vgdb=no ./mm input output

Thankfully my program is able to compile but once I try to execute the code I am receiving these type of valgrind errors.

```
Reading:         1902900ns
==54== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==54==    at 0x10962C: mult_matrices (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==    by 0x10922A: main (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==
==54== Invalid read of size 4
==54==    at 0x10962C: mult_matrices (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==    by 0x10922A: main (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==54==
==54==
==54== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==54==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0       
==54==    at 0x10962C: mult_matrices (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==    by 0x10922A: main (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack  
==54==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but 
==54==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the   
==54==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.  
==54==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==54== 800 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 6 of 6
==54==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==54==    by 0x1095B9: mult_matrices (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==    by 0x10922A: main (in /mnt/c/Source/Operating-Systems/matrix_Manipulation/mm)
==54==
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `Matrices_results[i][j] +=` The first valgrind error is likely due to thi sline. `Matrices_results` is allocated with `malloc` but the contents are not initialised. So you are using unintialised values.

Comment: `Matrices_results = malloc(matrices_size[1][1]);` Allocating that on every loop makes no sense. It means you are throwing away the previous allocation and data as well as causing memory leaks.

Comment: `Matrices_results = malloc(size);` Shortly followed by this inside a loop: `Matrices_results = malloc(matrices_size[1][1]);` causes a memory leak and I assume the logic is not doing whatever your intent is.

Comment: Is this a programming exercise? If not I would recommend that you use something like a linear algebra library (blaze, armadillo, eigen for instance).